# How can I get the text in the Perl/Tk Text widget?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have written a script that gets a file name and insert the file content to a [Text widget](http://p3rl.org/Tk::Text). Now when I close the script window, I need it to write the text onto the Unix screen.

How can I get the Text widget content?

My text widget insertion sorce code is:

```
open(FILE, $file_name);
foreach my $line (<FILE>) {
    $text->insert('end', $line);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$text->get('1.0','end-1c');
```

(It's `end-1c` – end less one character – for fairly technical reasons; with just `end` you'd get an extra newline appended. A known Tk gotcha.)

Comment: BTW, how you write it to the screen is up to you; there's *lots* of ways to do that…